# want to show xml file data in div in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

I have java script code , i just want to show xml data in div using html so i can display  content of xml data in html by using div

```
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        document.write("<tr><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td></tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
    </script>




 </head>
 <body onload="displayCD(2)">
 <div id='showCD'>
 </div>
```

Comment: So, whats your Question?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `document.write`.

Fetch the div you want, like:

```
var the_div = document.getElementByI("showCD");
```

Then set it's content (using a TextNode):

```
var text_node = document.createTextNode(xmlDoc);
the_div.appendChild(text_node);
```

or maybe `xmlhttp.responseText` instead of `.responseXML`. I don't know if `responseXML` is standard.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayCD(){
    alert(1);
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseXML);
            var tableData = "<table border='1'>";
            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                tableData += "<tr><td>"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td>";
                tableData += "<td>"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td></tr>";
            }
            document.getElementById('showCD').innerHTML=tableData;
        }
    }    
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayCD(2)">
<div id='showCD'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks For the code but now its not showing xml data on html page

Comment: can you provide cd_catalog.xml values. I mean <xml> tag format. it's in live xml file?

Comment: <CATALOG>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>kalpesh</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>kalpeshganekar@gmail.com</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>surya</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>suryakant@yahoo.com</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>viraj</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>virajkulakrni@gmail.com</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
 </CD>
 </CATALOG>

Comment: Please have look http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2. mean while am working on ur code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div>
<table id="cds">
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var xhr= window.XMLHttpRequest? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (this.readyState===4 || this.status===200)
            populateTable(this.responseXML);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', 'cd_catalog.xml', true);
    xhr.send();

    function populateTable(xml) {
        var table= document.getElementById('cds');
        var cds= xml.getElementsByTagName('CD');
        for (var i= 0; i<cds.length; i++) {
            var row= table.insertRow(-1);

            function getProperty(name) {
                var el= cds[i].getElementsByTagName(name)[0];
                if (el.firstChild)
                    return el.firstChild.data;
                return ''; // allow empty elements
            }
            function addCell(value) {
                row.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
            }

            addCell(getProperty('ARTIST'));
            addCell(getProperty('TITLE'));
        }
    };

</script>
```

Comment: i want to use div u have ot used div here, that div should be diplay on html

Comment: we dont want to use div to achieve your need..above code helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

It is not so complicated.

```
<body>
    <div id="showCD"></div>

    <script>

        var divCDs = document.getElementById('showCD'); 
        var List = xml.getElementsByTagName('CD');

       for (var i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {

            // dynamic DIV.
            var new_div = document.createElement('div');
            new_div.innerHTML = List[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE") [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            divCDs.appendChild(new_div);

       }

    </script>
</body>
```

[Check the complete code.](http://www.encodedna.com/2014/07/extract-data-from-an-xml-file-using-javascript.htm)